# Service fabric upgrade failing due to change in namespace

Tags: namespaces, upgrade, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric application stuck in "Upgrading" mode.
The exception is:

> Could not load type 'DB.IAddUser' from assembly 'DB' at
>   WebApi.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

My change was that of renaming the name space, from 'DB' to 'DB.Interfaces'.

This class is only used as a constructor dependency, and registered as such

Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IAddUser, AddUser>();
```

UserController.cs

```cs
private IAddUser addUser;
public UserController(IAddUser addUser){
   this.addUser = addUser;
}
```

Why would this cause SF to get stuck?

Additionally, it only got stuck on the last upgrade domain, and not on the others.

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken but if upgrade was successful on other upgrade domains then it is not code related issue.

Try to rollback the application upgrade and upgrade again:
`Start-ServiceFabricApplicationRollback -ApplicationName fabric:/MyApp`

[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricapplicationrollback?view=azureservicefabricps)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this had nothing to do with service fabric (as expected and as @SteppingRazor said). 
The problem seems to be related to MSBuild/Azure devops build task, I had upgraded nuget package

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild

from 1.6.7 to 1.6.8 and it seems that the build was still using older code (confirmed via a decompiler).

Reverting back to 1.6.7 solved the issue (albeit its just a workaround)